# Как отправить ответ в командную строку сразу после команды?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

В примере показано как работает код, но нужно чтобы ответ приходил не следующей командой, а продолжением запроса.

Например пишем `C:\app.exe /h /s /e` и в этой же строке получаем ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что ответ приходит новой командой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в файле Program.cs (приложение Windows Form):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var consoleWriter = new GUIConsoleWriter();
        var form = new Form1();
        bool needRun = true;

        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            switch (arg)
            {
                case "/h":
                    form.Check1();
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + "Команда /h выполнена");
                    needRun = false;
                    break;

                case "/s":
                    form.Check2();
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + "Команда /s выполнена");
                    needRun = false;
                    break;

                case "/e":
                    form.Check3();
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + "Команда /e выполнена");
                    needRun = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (needRun)
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }

    public class GUIConsoleWriter
    {
        private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

        StreamWriter ConsoleWriter;

        public GUIConsoleWriter()
        {
            var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            ConsoleWriter = new StreamWriter(stdout);
            ConsoleWriter.AutoFlush = true;

            AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    }
```

Comment: @Igor если убрать "\r\n", то это уберет только новую строку, прописывать будет как новую команду (т.е. появляется новый запрос в виде `C:\>` и в нем текст), а нужно, чтобы первая команда не завершалась, пока не отобразится ответ в виде текста.

Comment: Подозреваю что дело в создании GUIConsoleWriter, попробуйте не создавать его, потому что незачем присоединяться к консольному выводу заново когда он уже есть у консоли.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я нашел упрощение коду, но он все равно выводит ответ новой командой, через `C:\>` прикреплю код ответом.

Comment: Ответьте мне пожалуйста, а то я не догоняю - зачем вам в КОНСОЛЬНОЙ программе вызывать AttachConsole?

Comment: Посмотрите пример в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047741/attachconsole-1-but-console-writeline-wont-output-to-parent-command-prompt

Comment: @DanielProtopopov само приложения является Windows Form, обращение к приложению через **cmd** командную строку, если вы учитывали эти условия, то я понятия не имею зачем вызывать AttachConsole, мне главное результат, и он работает :) а без него не получается... суть в том, чтобы принять ответ от приложения внутри командной строки **cmd**

Comment: @DanielProtopopov по Вашей ссылке я уже все варианты испробовал, они примерно такие же, мне нужен результат как на первом изображении, ввели команду и тут же получили ответ с новой строки без `C:\>`

Comment: Посмотрите пример, данный выше. Там учитывается то что вам нужно вывести только результат, не создавая формы и делать вывод в консоль. Следуйте ему аналогично и вывод у вас должен быть в то же окно.

Comment: Думаю здесь проблема в том, что запуская программу WinForms из консоли, она создаётся и сама отключается от консоли т.к из неё был просто произведён запуск (также как если бы это было сделано из windows explorer). А уже после этого вы подсоединяетесь к этой консоли как корневому приложению, поэтому так оно и получается. Здесь скорее всего все правильно, и не думаю что можно как-то это обойти кроме разве предотвращения отсоединения от консоли, хотя это будет очень муторно и трудозатратно.

Comment: Получилось ли исправить проблему с выводом новой команды?

Answer (score 0):

Упрощенный код, но результат тот же (ответ приходит командой):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int procid);
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var form = new Form1();
        if (AttachConsole(-1))
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                switch (arg)
                {
                    case "/h":
                        form.Check1();
                        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + "Команда /h выполнена");
                        break;

                    case "/s":
                        form.Check2();
                        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + "Команда /s выполнена");
                        break;

                    case "/e":
                        form.Check3();
                        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + "Команда /e выполнена");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```